# I need to disallow whitespaces, forward and backward slash characters both at the starting and ending of the input string

Tags: json, pattern-matching

I need to disallow whitespaces, forward and backward slash characters both at the starting and ending of the input string, with json.

I tried this :
pattern:
`[ "^(?!\\s)[^/\\\\\\]*$" ]`
it restricts whitespaces, backward and forward slashes in the beginning of the string, but in the end of a string it restricts forward and backward slash characters but not whitespaces.
So, please suggest me a pattern to resolve this issue.